# Setting a request header in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, express-jwt

I'm quite new to NodeJS. Lately, I've been trying to create a Login page with authentication using JWT and I've been running into the same error for a week now.

Here is my logic though:

1. user sign up and is been given an access token using JWT via

```js
const token = jwt.sign({username:this.username, _id: this._id}, config.get('private keys));
req.headers.authorization = token;
```

2. While login in, I did this;

```js
const token = req.headers.authorization;
if(!token) return res.send("Access denied");
...
```

But then, every time I try to login, I always get Access denied, I don't know if it should be `req.headers.authorization` or `res.headers["authorization"]`, or if the problem is in the sign up page.

Comment: You need to provide the jwt token when users sign in. Your client side should send the token to the server on every request. It will not automatically be carried by the browser. Check the question and my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63644149/using-jwt-for-authorization-in-node/63644767#63644767

Comment: Don't `return` in a Express route handler function; calling `res.send(...)` or similar is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us how you are sending the http requests?
Normally, when using postman, you should get a token with your default login route and then add the token in a new header with "Authorization" name and "Token " in value.

Comment: I am not using postman actually, everything tends to work just fine on postman. it seems on my app, the token doesn't get transferred to the next request, i need to somehow store the token so it can exist for use upon multiple requests